# should I change facebook login code according to February 2013 Breaking Changes?

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter

In my website I implemented login with facebook. But Facebook announced in their [February 2013 breaking changes](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/#february-2013) that they are going to change some functionality.

According to this should I change my login code, or is authentication not affected by these changes?

Comment: I don't know. Are you using any features covered by the breaking changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the list of February 2013 Breaking Changes there is no direct mention of the authentication mechanism, but I would recommend you test your application as follows: In the application advanced settings, set the breaking changes to 'Enabled'. Then test your application functionality. If issues are found, you can reverse that setting while you remedy any issues.